# How to disable ability to show passwords without entering a password in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

If I give my computer to someone to use it with my account logged on that person could theoretically access the keyring application and see all my passwords by clicking *show password*.

Is there any way to prevent that? E.g. prompt for the login-password before showing any passwords?

The same is true for some other applications (only network-manager comes to mind at the moment.) Any person can just click *show password* to see the password I use to access a VPN, not exactly nice.

Is there any way to make my passwords more secure while still allowing other people to use my account?

Answer (score 0):

If you physically give someone your machine, there is little you can do to keep them out for long.  It doesn't matter if you are logged in or not, an unethical, determined person can get your passwords if they want them.  All they need is time.

If you think you have friends who might be crawling around in your personal files if you loan them your machine, then I suggest you either don't loan them you computer or you find new friends.